# How to set Application.version for desktop builds in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a system for checking version numbers of an application and prompting for updates, I would like to use Application.version for this.

Unfortunately I'm having some difficulty finding out where the version is set or where unity acquires the number from, at least on desktop platforms.

Has anyone had any success with setting version number in the editor or is this a post build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more likely to be handled by the store, it will show in the update section when a new version is released.

If you need to inform in game, then you would have a value stored in the app and a value stored on a server, compare those, if not the same, you put a banner with a link to the app store page of your app.

Comment: Thanks, using your advice I ended up using the assembly's version number for tracking internally.